# Record Audio Stream from getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, html, audio, webrtc, getusermedia

In recent days, I tried to use javascript to record audio stream.
I found that there is no example code which  works.

Is there any browser supporting?

Here is my code

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia; 

navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, gotStream, null);
function gotStream(stream) {

        msgStream = stream;        
        msgStreamRecorder = stream.record(); // no method record :(
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check this site:
https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

It stores the audio into a file (.wav) on the client side.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: The audio cannot be played using windows media player if I record and download from the link above. If I use windows media player and record audio using that thing then it's broken audio can be played if I download media player classic. Not even vlc can play that audio

Answer (score 35):

getUserMedia gives you access to the device, but it is up to you to record the audio.  To do that, you'll want to 'listen' to the device, building a buffer of the data.  Then when you stop listening to the device, you can format that data as a WAV file (or any other format).  Once formatted you can upload it to your server, S3, or play it  directly in the browser.

To listen to the data in a way that is useful for building your buffer, you will need a ScriptProcessorNode.  A ScriptProcessorNode basically sits between the input (microphone) and the output (speakers), and gives you a chance to manipulate the audio data as it streams.  Unfortunately the implementation is not straightforward.

You'll need:

- [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia) to access the device
- [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) to create a MediaStreamAudioSourceNode and a ScriptProcessorNode
- MediaStreamAudioSourceNode to represent the audio stream
- [ScriptProcessorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode) to get access to the streaming audio data via an onaudioprocessevent.  The event exposes the channel data that you'll build your buffer with.

Putting it all together:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true},
  function(stream) {
    // create the MediaStreamAudioSourceNode
    var context = new AudioContext();
    var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var recLength = 0,
      recBuffersL = [],
      recBuffersR = [];

    // create a ScriptProcessorNode
    if(!context.createScriptProcessor){
       node = context.createJavaScriptNode(4096, 2, 2);
    } else {
       node = context.createScriptProcessor(4096, 2, 2);
    }

    // listen to the audio data, and record into the buffer
    node.onaudioprocess = function(e){
      recBuffersL.push(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0));
      recBuffersR.push(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1));
      recLength += e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0).length;
    }

    // connect the ScriptProcessorNode with the input audio
    source.connect(node);
    // if the ScriptProcessorNode is not connected to an output the "onaudioprocess" event is not triggered in chrome
    node.connect(context.destination);
  },
  function(e) {
    // do something about errors
});
```

Rather than building all of this yourself I suggest you use the [AudioRecorder](https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder) code, which is awesome.  It also handles writing the buffer to a WAV file.  [Here is a demo](https://www.webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html).

Here's another [great resource](http://typedarray.org/from-microphone-to-wav-with-getusermedia-and-web-audio/).

Comment: `ScriptProcessorNode` is now deprecated - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode

Answer (score 7):

for browsers that support [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder_API), use it.

for older browsers that does not support MediaRecorder API, there are three ways to do it

1. as `wav`

   - all code client-side.
   - uncompressed recording.
   - source code --> http://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs
2. as `mp3`

   - all code client-side.
   - compressed recording.
   - source code --> http://github.com/Mido22/mp3Recorder
3. as `opus packets`  (can get output as `wav`, `mp3` or `ogg`)

   - client and server(`node.js`) code.
   - compressed recording.
   - source code --> http://github.com/Mido22/recordOpus

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug that currently does not allow audio only. Please see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112367

Answer (score -2):

Currently, this is not possible without sending the data over to the server side. However, this would soon become possible in the browser if they start supporting the [MediaRecorder working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/).

Comment: Here is the bug tracker for this Feature [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113676)