# Web Audio API on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-audio-api

I'm trying to test this [audio recording example](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) on Android devices with Chrome.
According to [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api) `Web Audio API` should be available on Android Chrome 37.

The RecordRTC developer wrote [here](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC)

> RecordRTC uses WebAudio API for stereo-audio recording. AFAIK, WebAudio is not supported on android chrome releases, yet.

But now, it is listed as supported, so I assumed it should work.

I ran the following tests (all with the demo [page](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/))

- Chrome 37 on windows - Works
- Chrome 37 on Galaxy S4 Androind - fails
- Chrome 37 on Nexus 7 Androind - fails
- Chrome 38 Beta on Nexus Androind - fails
- Chrome 37 on Galaxy Nexus Androind - fails

Any advice on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19238153/1363) recording method instead, and it seems to work on Android+Chrome